# Como configurar o Auditor usando o Spring Boot 2.0.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Eis uma classe que eu usava com o spring framework versao `4.3.4.RELEASE` (eu ainda não usava o spring boot) e que funcionava:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

public class SpringSecurityAuditor implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || authentication.getPrincipal().equals("anonymousUser")) {

            return authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
        }

        return ((UsuarioLogado) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    }

}
```

e aqui a que estou tentando implementar com o spring boot 2.0.2:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

public class SpringSecurityAuditor implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || authentication.getPrincipal().equals("anonymousUser")) {

            return (Optional<String>) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
        return ... código a  ser implementado...
    }
}
```

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.Como posso implementar esse metodo?

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-auditing-part-two/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irei considerar a sua implementação antiga, que retorna `String`, não uma entidade de usuário, por exemplo. Além disto, não vou considerar nada que leve a crer que você está usando coisas customizadas para detalhes de usuário, *security holder/manager*, etc.

Neste caso, a única alteração é que agora é retornado um [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) - [`AuditorAware` 1.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.9.x/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AuditorAware.html), [`AuditorAware` atual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AuditorAware.html). A implementação será basicamente a mesma, apenas o retorno alterado, algo como o abaixo:

```
public class SpringSecurityAuditor implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        String currentAuditor;
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || authentication.getPrincipal().equals("anonymousUser")) {
            currentAuditor = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
        } else {
            currentAuditor = ((UsuarioLogado) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername()
        }
        return Optional.of(currentAuditor);
    }

}
```

Vale observar que isto não tem necessariamente relação com *Spring Boot*, a *interface* vem do *Spring Data*, no caso do *Commons*. Relacionado diretamente ao *Boot*, a configuração ficou mais simplificada, mas aí é outra questão.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara!